# Mark maze solution path with consecutive alphabet characters

Tags: python, for-loop, maze

I'm working on a maze solver, and while I have everything working functionally, I can't get one portion to work. I need to mark the 'solution path' with ascending letters of the alphabet (a-z) instead of a single character.

I cannot get it to continue to iterate over a list of alphabet characters, the best I've achieved is it stopping at the letter 'a' and just changing all letters to that.

The maze:

```
###_###
#_____#
#_##_##
#_##__#
#_#####
```

The 'solved maze':

```
###a###
#aaa__#
#a##_##
#a##__#
#a#####
```

The code:

```
PATH = "_"
START = "_"
VISITED = "."
SOLUTION = "o"

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, ascii_maze):
        # splits maze string into separate values on each new line
        # uses list comp. to create 'matrix' out of maze
        self.maze = [list(row) for row in ascii_maze.splitlines()]
        # finds index first '_' character which denotes the beginning
        self.start_y = [row.count(START) for row in self.maze].index(1)
        # finds position where '_' is located within the 'y' line which returns the index position
        self.start_x = self.maze[self.start_y].index(START)

    # returns string representation of maze object, joining maze elements passed in as parameters
    # used to print maze with 'cells' and be user friendly
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join("".join(row) for row in self.maze)

    def solve_maze(self, x=None, y=None):
        # assigns starting (x,y) position
        if x is None:
            x, y = self.start_x, self.start_y
        # checks if the coordinate is in the path/start
        if self.maze[y][x] in (PATH, START):
            # marks spot as 'visited' for recursion check
            self.maze[y][x] = VISITED
            # uses recursion to check paths by checking each direction and making a decision off that
            try:
                if (self.solve_maze(x+1, y) or
                        self.solve_maze(x-1, y) or
                        self.solve_maze(x, y+1) or
                        self.solve_maze(x, y-1)):
                    self.maze[y][x] = SOLUTION
                    return True
            # this exception is what occurs when the program tries to leave the maze (aka it found the exit)
            # also marks it
            except IndexError:
                self.maze[y][x] = SOLUTION
                return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    alphabet_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','l', 'm', 'n',
                     'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    # for checking mazes through terminal
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        maze = Maze(open(sys.argv[1]).read())
    # if none available, defaults to 'maze' text file
    else:
        maze = Maze(open('maze').read())
    # prints string representation of maze to replace "visited" areas (. char used for testing) with original "_"
    if maze.solve_maze():
        # converting to string allows for easy replacement of things
        maze = str(maze)
        maze = maze.replace(".", "_")
        for char in maze:
            if char == "o":
                for item in alphabet_list:
                    maze = maze.replace(char, item)

    print(maze)
```

Comment: What does the (solved) maze in the string form look like? Got an example? I'm pretty sure your issue is here `for item in alphabet_list: maze = maze.replace(char, item)`

Comment: Hi there, I'll edit with example.

Comment: Hm, no, I meant it's state here: `maze = maze.replace(".", "_")`. What does `print(maze)` look like here?

Comment: At that point it prints out the edited version I posted, except with the original 'solution line' characters ("o"). After `maze = maze.replace(".", "_")` the "." chars, which are used to denote 'visited' for the recursion, are replaced by "_". Before it, there are periods denoting where the program checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to set the solution character as its solved (its really hard to recreate this after the fact by just unaware string manipulations, it would essentially be re-navigating the whole solution path):

We'll use a helper function to return to us the next character in the alphabet, resetting at 'z':

```
SOLUTION = ord('a') - 1
def getSolutionChar():
    global SOLUTION
    if SOLUTION >= ord('z'):
        SOLUTION = ord('a')
    else:
        SOLUTION += 1
    return chr(SOLUTION)
```

A replacement for the `try` block:

```
        try:
            if (self.solve_maze(x+1, y) or
                self.solve_maze(x-1, y) or
                self.solve_maze(x, y+1) or
                self.solve_maze(x, y-1)):
                self.maze[y][x] = getSolutionChar()
                return True
        except IndexError:
            self.maze[y][x] = getSolutionChar()
            return True
```

Don't forget to remove the following, since it's no longer needed:

```
alphabet_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','l', 'm', 'n',
                 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    for char in maze:
        if char == "o":
            for item in alphabet_list:
                maze = maze.replace(char, item)
```

Comment: This worked, although only about 90%. It now has the alphabet working, but the order is wrong. It should start at a (at the top), then have b below, c to the left, then d to the left. The letters going down after that are correct though. Any hints on how to get that fixed?

Comment: Yea, I was afraid of that. You create the solution path using a static 'o'. You should instead use the dynamic character selection I'm using there instead of `SOLUTION`, I think. You can't redetermine the path with a blanket replace after you solve it. You need to do that during the solve.

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure that's why that's happening. Could I possibly nest this into the solving logic to just append the letters as they go instead of changing them after the fact?

Comment: Should be able to. I'd replace `SOLUTION` with the dynamic character selection I have.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try to post again soon if I get it to work :)

Comment: Oh, and if the letters show up backwards, just start at 'z' and `-=` down to 'a' in the helper function. Possibility due to the depth first recursion.

Comment: Seem to be getting an error now.
line 71, in <module>
    maze = str(maze) ////
 line 29, in __repr__
    return "\n".join("".join(row) for row in self.maze)
line 29, in <genexpr> ////
    return "\n".join("".join(row) for row in self.maze) //// 
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, int found

Edit: added //// to split the errors

Comment: Oh snap, I'm dumb, `chr(SOLUTION)`. See my edited helper.

Comment: There we go! Thank you SO much! This was bugging me forever.